# Bootstrap, why are products displayed arbitrarily?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Have a website in three languages. The porducts select from a mysql database  and showed wiht a do-while-loop.

```html
<!-- Shop Page Area Start-->
<div class="shoppage-area">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="about-desc">
      <h2>
        <?php echo $page['subtitle']; ?>
      </h2>
      <?php echo $page['content']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <?php
     do {
     ?>
        <!--Product Start-->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="sngle-product">
            <div class="product-thumb">
              <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $product['img']; ?>" alt=""/></a>
              <h2>
                <a href="#">
                  <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                </a>
              </h2>
            </div>
            <h3>
              <?php echo $product['desc']; ?>
            </h3>
            <span><?php echo $product['size']; ?></span>&nbsp;<span class="price"><?php echo $product['price']; ?> LE</span>
            <div class="product-overlay">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="product-quantity">
                    <div class="input-number">
                      <input type="text" value="1" name="quantity">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="orderbtn" href="#" data-uid="<?php echo $product['uniqueid']; ?>">ORDER</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Product End -->
        <?php
     } while ($product = $res->fetch_assoc()) ?>

    </div>
    <!-- end Row -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in one language showed correctly and in the other i get a lot spaces between the products. See the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bUNx.jpg)

How i can solve this

Comment: why a do-while? On the first iteration you won't have a product yet...

Comment: This behaviour is because not every height of every product is the same.. So either give them all the same height, or use something like masonry to fix it..

Comment: wich loop you prefer? In french shows right. From where i get the space in exp. english or german

Comment: a normal while loop. With a [do..while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) the block will _always_ run at least once, because at the _end_ of the loop the expression is checked. But you asign the `$product` also in the truth expression. That means that at the first iteration there's no `$product` (unless you've assigned it before already, but that would be bad design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional class `flex-row` to the product wrapping `row` element. And try applying the following styles.

```
.flex-row{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip.

Comment: Good luck. Let me know the status of the issue after applying the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your column like this

```
 <div class="shoppage-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="about-desc">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <?php $i=1;
        do {
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="sngle-product">
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo "test"; ?>" alt=""/></a>
                    <h2><a href="#"><?php echo "test"; ?></a> </h2>   
                </div>
                <h3><?php echo ($i==2)? " testtesttesttesttesttest testtesttesttest test": "test"; ?></h3>
                <span><?php echo "test"; ?></span>&nbsp;<span class="price"><?php echo 12321; ?> LE</span>
                <div class="product-overlay">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="product-quantity">
                                <div class="input-number">
                                    <input type="text" value="1" name="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="orderbtn" href="#" data-uid="<?php echo "1231"; ?>">ORDER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        echo $i%4;
        if($i%4== 0 && $i > 1) {
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
        $i++;
        } while ($i<=10) ?>
   </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice this method, because what happens if you get to a smaller screen? Then you might still get the same problem..

Comment: I try this before. @Naruto say right. I got the same problem